# Do the projection errors resulting from linear projections onto each other satisfy any equality restriction?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, expected-value, inner-products, projection

Suppose I have two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ that are not independent of each other. Consider the linear projections of $X_1X_2$ and $X_1$ onto each other: $L(X_1X_2|X_1)$ and $L(X_1|X_1X_2)$, where $L(A|B)\equiv (E(A^2))^{-1}E(AB)B$.

Define the projection errors as: $e_1\equiv X_1X_2-L(X_1X_2|X_1)=X_1X_2-(E(X_1^2))^{-1}E(X_1^2X_2)X_1$  and $e_{12}\equiv X_1-L(X_1|X_1X_2)=X_1-(E(X_1^2 X_2^2))^{-1}E(X_1^2 X_2)X_1X_2$.

My question is, do $e_1$ and $e_{12}$ together satisfy any equality restriction or identity? (Since they are the projection erros that result from linear projections of two random variables onto each other, I guess they should be related somehow) If there isn't any equality or identity in general, what about the case when $E(X_1)=0$ and $E(X_1X_2)=0$?

Comment: Your projection errors already assume $\mathbb{E}(X_1) = 0, \mathbb{E}(X_1X_2) = 0$. Otherwise, the projection errors will have different forms. Also, what do you expect the relationship about $e_1$ and $e_{12}$ ? (Expectation, Variance, etc.?)

Comment: @ThanhNguyen Thanks! Can you explain a bit more? I still can't see why $E(X_1)=E(X_1X_2)=0$ is already assumed. Regarding the relation I expect, I was thinking about the analog in the finite dimensional vector space like in R^3, where e1 and e12 are the sides of right triangles similar to each other.

Comment: The linear projection $L(X_1X_2 \vert X_1 ) = a + bX_1$ for some constant $a$ and $b$. We know that $a$ and $b$ must satisfy the following set of equations:
$$
    \begin{cases}
           \mathbb{E}(X_1 X_2 - a - bX_1) =  0\\
           \mathbb{E}((X_1 X_2 - a - bX_1)X_1) = 0
    \end{cases}
$$
If $\mathbb{E}(X_1) = 0, \mathbb{E}(X_1X_2) = 0$ then $a = 0, b = -\dfrac{\mathbb{E}(X_1^2X_2)}{\mathbb{E}(X_1^2)}$, which is the exact form of $L(X_1X_2 \vert X_1)$ in your question. Otherwise, the form for $a$ and $b$ is much more complicated.